# Don't offer non-file-name as a file name in find-file

Tags: find-file, filenames, ffap

When opening a file with `find-file`, the default entry in the minibuffer is the current directory. If I press <kbd>Down</kbd>, I see the [name of the current file](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FindFile#toc2) (if the current buffer is visiting a file).

Sometimes, if I press <kbd>Down</kbd>, I see what seems to be a guess of a file name in the current buffer, and I need to press <kbd>Down</kbd> twice. How can I customize this “guess of a file name”?

Specifically, I often edit files that contain `/**` and this is offered at the `find-file` prompt even though it isn't a file name. How can I avoid getting offered to open `/**`?

I'm using Emacs 24.5 but I want to keep compatibility with other Emacs versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from [ffap](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/FFAP.html) (find file at point), as the name might suggest. Specifically, `find-file` uses `read-file-name` to read its input, which in turn calls `read-file-name-default` unless overridden through the variable `read-file-name-function`. `read-file-name-default` calls the auxiliary function `read-file-name--defaults` to build the initial inputs: current directory, file name at point (if non-nil), and current file name (if non-nil). The file name at point is the first function from `file-name-at-point-functions` that returns non-nil, and this list of functions contains `ffap-guess-file-name-at-point` by default. For our purposes, this function is a wrapper around `ffap-file-at-point`.

To completely turn off the file-name-at-point feature of `find-file` and other functions that prompt for a file name, you can advise `read-file-name--defaults` or `read-file-name-default` or `read-file-name`. Untested:

```
(defadvice read-file-name
  (around read-file-name-no-ffap activate)
  (let ((file-name-at-point-functions nil))
    ad-do-it))
```

To skip not-really-a-file-name strings such as `/**`, from all uses of `ffap-file-at-point`, you can advise `ffap-file-at-point`.

```
(defadvice ffap-file-at-point
    (after ffap-file-at-point-false-positives activate compile)
  "Omit certain false positives from the guesses."
  (if (save-match-data
        (and ad-return-value
             ;; If it doesn't have at least one letter, it's probably
             ;; not a file name.
             (not (string-match "[A-Za-z]" ad-return-value))))
      (setq ad-return-value nil)))
```

(This answer uses the “classic” advice interface that's compatible with older Emacs version. If you don't care about old versions, you may want to port them to the [modern advice interface](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Porting-old-advice.html#Porting-old-advice).)